Empirical factors vs PCA factors representation
I have performed a Principal Component Analysis on Matlab on a time series of US Treasury yields from 1990 to the present, which determines a $n \times m$ matrix $Y$, where $n = 8577$ are the observations, i.e. the number of days, while $m = 120$ are the interest rates for different time to maturities; in particular $\tau = {0.25:0.25:30}$.
The algorithm worked on the on the covariance matrix of $Y$ centered by columns.
My goal was to compare the three principal components, that are theorized like the level, the slope and the curvature of the yield curve over time, with their empirical meaning. In this sense:

empirical level: 10Y yield
empirical slope: - 10Y + 3M yields
empirical curvature: 3M - 2*5Y + 10Y yields

The three factors have been represented by the first three columns of the output score from pca Matlab command.
In order to make the comparison, I standardized both the PC and the empirical factors, subtracting their mean and dividing by their standard deviation. However, in the case of the slope and the curvature, the factor representation doesn't fit so well the empirical counterparts when I divide by the standard deviation too.

The figure represents my results ("no standardized" means that I just subtracted the mean from the original $Y$, without dividing by the standard deviation too; instead, the PC factors, score, are properly standardized in both the cases).
Is this unperfect fit due to any conceptual/programming mistake or is it reasonable?
